# mysql php query string contains words that start with input

Tags: mysql

Is there a built in way in mysql to query columns that contains specific word(s) and the word(s) also start with the input.

For instance, input is "EF"

```
#1 ABCD EFGH    <- Want this one
#2 BCDE FGHA 
#3 CDEF GHAB
#4 EFGH ABCD    <- And this one
```

If I query `%EF%`, it'll give me the #1, #3 and #4, if I query `EF%`, it's only going to give #4.

So essentially, I want to know if mysql can firstly do a `preg_split` like in PHP, then query `EF%`, or something along the line of that.

Comment: `% EF% not working?

Comment: There is space there

Comment: @AleksaRistic but then if the first part of the string starts with EF, it's not going to work. I'm going to edit for more clarity.

Comment: There are regular expressions for MySQL too, I'd give that a go. You *could* use `LIKE '% EF%`, but that wouldn't work if you had input like `AB` (and expect the first row).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regular expression. In MySQL, the regexp pattern `[[:<:]]` matches the beginning of a word, so you can do:

```
WHERE column REGEXP '[[:<:]]EF'
```

[Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html)

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here. Just came up with a solution, not pretty but it works.

I just changed my parameter into this

```
((Column LIKE '%...%' AND Column LIKE '% ...%') Or (Column LIKE '...%')) AND ...
```

Going to leave this here for a day and see if anyone has a better solution.

Comment: You don't need `LIKE '%...%'`

Answer (score 0):

If your column has two words, then you can use `SUBSTR()` and `LOCATE()`.

```
+--------------------------------+
| MyColumn                       |
+--------------------------------+
| Apple Effect                   |
| Effortless Orange              |     
+--------------------------------+
```

.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        *,
        SUBSTR(@values,1,LOCATE(' ',MyColumn)-1) AS FirstWord
        SUBSTR(@values,LOCATE(' ',@values)+1) AS SecondWord
    FROM MyTable
) AS X
WHERE FirstWord LIKE 'EF%'
OR SecondWord LIKE 'EF%'
```

If your column has more than two words, then things are a little more complex, but you can use `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` to find the Nth instance.

```
+--------------------------------+
| MyColumn                       |
+--------------------------------+
| The Perfect Apple Effect       |
| The Special Effortless Orange  |     
+--------------------------------+
```

.
`SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@values,' ',4),' ',-1)` = Gets the fourth word.

More examples and information can be found [here](http://www.giannistsakiris.com/2015/01/23/mysql-select-the-n-th-element-from-a-delimiter-separated-value-set/).